# A simple quantity drop down options with price and button link change

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a drop down with 3 options. I want the price change and also the link to that option change in the button. Any suggestion? Thank you

```
<form method="post" action="/" class="product-item">
<input type="hidden" value="10" name="price">
<select id="menu" name="quantity" class="product-select" tabindex="1">
<option class="list" value="1" value="google.com">1</option>
<option class="list" value="2" value="youtube.com">3</option>
<option class="list" value="3" value="pinterest.com/">6</option>
</select>
<div class="total-price">10</div>
</form>
<button id="desktop" onclick="gotosite()">
BUY NOW
</button>

<button id="desktop" onclick="gotosite()">
BUY NOW
</button>

<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script>
jQuery('.product-select').on('change', function() {
var el = $(this);
var quantity = parseInt(el.val());
var price = parseInt(el.closest('.product- 
item').find('[name="price"]').val());
el.closest('.product-item').find('.total-price').text(quantity * price);
});

function gotosite() {
window.location = document.getElementById("menu").value;
}
</script>
```

Comment: your html is invalid. you have 2 `value` attributes for each `<option>`

Comment: So how do i fix this? Because my goal is when you select one of the option the price text will change and also the link in the button

Comment: your question is hard to understand.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion. I'm trying to create a drop down with 3 options. When you select one of the option, the text price will change and also the link the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the 3rd option when you run this!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


$('.product-select').on('change', function() {
var el = $(this);
var x = document.getElementById("menu").value;
var quantity = [1,3,6];
var price = parseInt(el.closest('.product-item').find('[name="price"]').val());
var sum = (quantity[x] * price);

//document.getElementById('total-price').innerHTML=sum;

$("#total-price").text(sum);
});

function gotosite() {
var x = document.getElementById("menu").value;

var urls =['https://google.com','https://yahoo.com','https://stackoverflow.com'];

window.location=urls[x];
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="/" class="product-item">
<input type="hidden" value="10" name="price">
<select id="menu" name="quantity" class="product-select" tabindex="1">
<option class="list" value="0" >1</option>
<option class="list" value="1" >3</option>
<option class="list" value="2" >6</option>
</select>
<div id="total-price">10</div>
</form>
<button id="desktop1" onclick="gotosite()">
BUY NOW
</button>

<button id="desktop2" onclick="gotosite()">
BUY NOW
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It worked for first and second option but not the third

Comment: oh wait never mind, it works for the third option. So how do i make it work for the other two?

Comment: it will work for all the options just not on stackoverflow website.  they restrict the window.location to stackoverflow.com

Comment: ok it works now. But how about the price change? Sorry for asking too much, I'm new to coding. I set the input value to 10 so when option one is selected the number should change to 10, option two should change to 30, three should change to 60.